# 'Connection reset by peer' on lftp while uploading files

Tags: networking, server, ftp

I am working on a project where several Raspberry Pis gather sensor data and log them to several files, several times a day. I wanted to write a small script to upload all those files to an FTP server at the end of the day with crontab. So I wrote a script using lftp which worked at first but later started showing error.

Below is the script and verbose output. How can I fix it?

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    HOST='ftp://xyz.com'
    USER='xxxxxx'
    PASS='xxxxxx'
    TARGETFOLDER='/home/xxxx'
    SOURCEFOLDER='/home/pi/yyyy'

    lftp -f "
    open $HOST
    user $USER $PASS
    debug -o lftp_debug.txt
    lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
    mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
    bye
    "
```

output:

```
---- Connecting to xyz.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 21   
<--- 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)   
---> FEAT    
<--- 211-Features:   
<---  EPRT    
<---  EPSV    
<---  MDTM    
<---  PASV   
<---  REST STREAM    
<---  SIZE 
<---  TVFS
<--- 211 End    
---> USER XXXX  
<--- 331 Please specify the password.    
---> PASS XXXX   
<--- 230 Login successful.   
---> PWD   
<--- 257 "/home/XXXX" is the current directory   
---> MKD /home   
<--- 550 Create directory operation failed.    
---> MKD /home/XXXX
<--- 550 Create directory operation failed.
---- CWD path to be sent is `/home/XXXX'  
---> CWD /home/XXXX   
<--- 250 Directory successfully changed.    
---> PASV    
**** control-socket: Connection reset by peer
---- Closing data socket   
---- Closing control socket
```

##***UPDATE 2***##

Funny thing is when I log into the same FTP server through 'FTP' command with the same user and pass it works like a charm but when I log in through `lftp` with the same user and pass I was able to log into the server but as soon as I give `ls` command it shows the following output.

```
lftp user@xyz.com:~> ls
`ls' at 0 [Delaying before reconnect: 24]
```

##***UPDATE 3***##

I tried using SFTP instead and it worked properly. Hope this saves someone's time.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script?

Comment: Do you control both servers?  Its probably easier and more secure to use scp or rsync over ssh   rsync --archive -v $SOURCEFOLDER/ $USER@$HOST:$TARGETFOLDER/

Comment: One reason for SSH is that you use only one port,  ftp uses two and it looks from the output that your problem is related to that.  Setting up firewalls for FTP is more complicated that with ssh.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use ftp. The problem you are having are likely related to the general confusion of connection direction in FTP. FTP uses two ports: One command connection, and one data connection. Traditionally the command connection was from client to server, and the data connection from server to client!

PASV is the opposite; it instructs the server to listen for the data connection from the client, and tell the client it's port number. It looks like this (unexpected to many) behavior is what's biting you.

However, in my opinion, continuing to use FTP is not an good alternative today. It's simply outdated, security wise and protocol wise.

You have several alternatives to FTP. If you use authentication, scp/sftp is a good alternative. It requires exactly one port, is authenticated and encrypted.

If you require anonymous submissions, http(s) is a good alternative. Either through a POST request, or with WebDAV. Http can *also* be set up to use authentication, and can be encrypted with TLS (https). It also opens only a single channel for both data and commands.

FTP is a 40 year old protocol. It's falling out of use, and as a consequence the software is not receiving as much attention as more popular webservers and ssh servers, and thus there's a higher chance of serious vulnerabilities surviving in the source code.

In addition the command for SCP'ing would be far simpler: `scp * $user@$host:$targetfolder` - and you could use key based authentication to avoid passwords in the script!